# Ocpsoft Rewrite JSF subdomain

Tags: jsf, url-rewriting, ocpsoft-rewrite

I want to create the following scenario:

#### 1. Step:

Login page: The user will login into the web portal.
Each user has an username. For example `tester12345`.
This username is stored in the database.

#### 2. Step:

After the redirect from the login page, all pages should be in this format:

`http://tester12345.domain.com/..`

This means: `{username}.domain.com/..`

How can I do this?

Comment: No websites have been seen so far that use this sort of URLs. Why not use REST like things instead in which you can meet with URLs such as  those you see on this site (stackoverflow.com including other sites in its network)?

Comment: @Tiny: never seen https://zeef.com? It uses basically the same technique, albeit for a completely different functional requirement.

Comment: @BalusC : I visited several times but did not (much) concentrate on the incoming URLs in the address bar. :)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do something like this:

```
.addRule(Join.path("/").to("/internal_resource_blah.jsp"))
.when(Direction.isInbound()
   .and(Domain.matches("username")
   .and(***username is in database***)))
.otherwise(SendError.code(404, "Page not found or some error."))

.addRule()
.when(Direction.isOutbound()
   .andNot(URL.matches("http://{username}.domain.com{suffix}"))
   .and(***user is logged in***))
.perform(Substitution.with("http://{loggedInUser}.domain.com{suffix}"))
```

Comment: Hi Lincoln, thank you - and where are the parameter are coming from? {username} ? What do you mean with {suffix} and what is {loggedInUser}? Which kind of code you I need in the JSF page and in one of my beans?

Comment: Hi. The parameters are created using Rewrite parameterization: https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/configuration/parameters.asciidoc

Comment: To add integration with JSF, you need to add the respective Rewrite extension: https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/integration/cdi.asciidoc